# TikZ baseline option not working

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get a straight line slightly higher than the base of the text. Something like this

[image: goal]

but this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
% \let\latinencoding\relax

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    Después, se marca con una \tikz{\draw [baseline = {(0ex, -0.5ex)}, thick] (0ex, 0.5ex) -- (1.5ex, 0.5ex)} debajo de
    cada \( \times \) que esté sola en una columna

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: struggle]

replacing that `\tikz` command with

```
\tikz{\path (0ex, 0ex)
    -- +(1.5ex, 0ex); \draw [thick] (0ex, 0.5ex) -- (1.5ex, 0.5ex)}
```

fixes it. Is this the only way to get this to work?

Comment: `baseline` is option for `\tikz` not for `\draw`. Use it like this `\tikz[baseline={(0,0)}]...`. Or even better `\tikz[baseline = 0]...`

Comment: thanks, what a silly error. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, it can be useful to somebody else. But probably rename it to something like "baseline option not working" to help googling ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as say [Kpym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9335/kpym) in his comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
% \let\latinencoding\relax
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}% needed since you use spanish babel which change some "tikz" internals...

\begin{document}
Después, se marca con una 
    \tikz[baseline]{\draw[thick] (0ex, 0.5ex) -- + (1.5ex, 0ex);} % <--- corrected
debajo de cada 
    \( \times \) 
que esté sola en una columna
\end{document}
```

[image]